# The dropdown view of AutoCompleteTextView displays with an error width

Tags: android

I follow the official [instruction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView) of autocompletetextview to create a new one in my project. I think that is easy, but when I run the code, I find the outcome is far from my expectation.

[image]

As you can see on the picture, when I type "f" in the textview, the dropdown view which is supposed to display "Franch", only displayed "Fr..", though I have add "setDropDownWidth(100)" to the textview.

I really want to know what happen and how to solve it.

And below is my code:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/countries_list"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.autocompletetextview;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
            "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
        textView.setThreshold(1);
        textView.setDropDownWidth(100);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurred because of this `textView.setDropDownWidth(100)`. It too small so the text will be wrap.

My solution is just remove it, so the autocomplete will wrap your edittext width, or `setDropDownWidth` with a bigger value.

Comment: I remove the setDropDownWidth, but this time the dropdownview doesn't even display a single word (the dropdown view is a blank area). And if I setDropDownWidth(200), it will works well. So yes you are right, 100 is too small. Also, I find out that if I set the `android:layout_width` as a fixed length, such as 100dp, then the code in Mainactivity will work without setDropDownWidth. You reply has inpired me, thanks